# how to fix this javascript program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code as following:

```
var data_array = [];
readData('file.txt');
console.log(data_array[0]);
console.log(data_array[1]);
console.log(data_array.length.toString());
console.log(data_array[data_array.length-1]);

//reads file into array
function readData(filepath) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    if (fs.existsSync(filepath)) {
        var array = fs.readFileSync(filepath).toString().split("\n");
        var data_array = array.slice(7,array.length - 2);
    } else {
        process.exit();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I got following

```
undefined
undefined
0
undefined
```

See Data_array is used within the if statement.
I think the array did not receive anything, that is why it is printing nothing but undefined and its length is 0.

How can I enforce it execute step by step these lines in the written order

```
var data_array = [];
readData('file.txt');   
console.log(data_array[0]);
console.log(data_array[1]);
 ....
```

Comment: Your `readData` function is saving to a local variable, not the global one you are console logging.

Comment: data_array is an empty array and never gets modified. what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Jecoms, i realized that now, thx

Comment: @manonthemat, got it, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing, because you are creating local scope variable and it shadows global. To fix, replace `var data_array = array...` with `data_array = array...`.

Also, keep in mind that you are using few antipatterns:

First, don't check for file existence before reading it — because it's possible for someone to delete file between your checks. Instead, just read it and handle exception.

Second, read file with `readFileSync(filepath, { encoding: 'utf8' })` — this will return the string right away, so you won't need `toString()`.

Third — `array.slice()` supports negative indexes (they count from the end of array), so you can literally have `array.slice(7, -2)`.

And in general, unless this is a single use throw-away code, I'd suggest you to use asynchronous function counterparts:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

// reads file into array
const readData = Promise.coroutine(function *(filepath) {
    try {
        const array = (yield fs.readFileAsync(filepath, { encoding: 'utf8' })
                      ).split("\n");
        const data_array = array.slice(7, -2);

        return data_array;
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit();
    }
});

Promise.coroutine(function *() {
    const data_array = yield readData('file.txt');
    console.log(data_array[0]);
    console.log(data_array[1]);
    console.log(data_array.length.toString());
    console.log(data_array[data_array.length-1]);
})();
```

Comment: or better return data_array and assign it

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, used var in declaration and later again in front of data-array.  lol ...

Comment: I tried  your code, but some error reported. trying to fix it now

Comment: await and async is causing "unexpected identifier" , so removed them then worked fine. thanks a lot

Comment: @alim, well, they are part of ECMAScript7, and your environment does not support them yet. You can either use [babel transpiler](http://babeljs.io/) (which I would recommend anyway to keep your code as modern as possible), or you can use generator-based coroutines — I had updated my answer to reflect that.